# d3 line does not draw

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've a problem here. The d3.line() is not showing any lines based on the data provided.

I've tried to print out the values via console.log and it fits the scale. [I've checked this link about the scaling issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049283/d3-line-chart-line-not-drawing)

I followed [this page](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) but modified it to suit the data given to me. I was wondering if the modifications made broke the code.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#line-graph"),
margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d, i) { console.log(i); return i; })
   .y(function(d) { console.log(d); return d; });

d3.json("Data2.json", function(data) {
    x.domain([0, data.length]);
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d1) { return d1.week; }));

    var arrWeek = function(data1) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++)
        arr.push(data1[i].week);
    return arr;
    }

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .select(".domain");

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("No. of commits");   

    g.append("path")
        .datum(arrWeek(data))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line); 
    });
```

EDIT: The graph just displays the values scale without any line drawn for the data.

EDIT 2: My apologies. I'm using d3.v4.min.js. As for Data2.json, here are 2 elements as it is quite long:

```
[
 {
"days": [
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0
],
"total": 1,
"week": 1457827200
},
{
"days": [
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0,
  3,
  1
],
"total": 5,
"week": 1458432000
}
]
```

EDIT 3: I'm drawing only the "week" variable, hence the scale would be [0, Data2.length] for x-axis. Hope it clears some doubt.

Comment: you did now show us the data (`Data2.json`).......Also you did not say which D3 version you are using.... shame shame shame

Comment: Your problem **is** a scale problem. I din't closed this question as a duplicate because it would seem rude, since you linked the very question I'd reference to close this one, saying that it didn't fix your problem. But it **does** fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use your scales in the line generator:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return x(i);
    //scale ---^
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d);
    //scale ---^
    });
```

It may not be your case, but this error normally occurs because people mistake the `x` and `y` in the line generator for the `x` and `y` in the scales names. That's why it's always a good practice to give meaningful names for your variables and objects: `xScale`, `yScale`, `xAxis`, `yAxis` etc...

Besides that, when you say...

> I've tried to print out the values via console.log and it fits the scale

... this is not accurate. Those are simply the data values, not related to the SVG coordinates system (unless you use your scales).

Here is your working code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
 {
"days": [
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0
],
"total": 1,
"week": 1457827200
},
{
"days": [
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0,
  3,
  1
],
"total": 5,
"week": 1458432000
}
];

var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d, i) {  return x(i); })
   .y(function(d) { return y(d); });


    x.domain([0, data.length]);
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d1) { return d1.week; }));

    var arrWeek = function(data1) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++)
        arr.push(data1[i].week);
    return arr;
    }

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .select(".domain");

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("No. of commits");   

    g.append("path")
        .datum(arrWeek(data))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="500"></svg>
```